# Is it possible to change a users SFTP password (renci.sshnet)

Tags: c#, sftp, change-password, ssh.net

Does anyone know if it is possible to programmatically change a users password on an SFTP site using SSH.NET library (Renci.SshNet)?  I have not been able to find anything definitive either way.

If it is I would appreciate any pointers you can provide.

Comment: http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/SSH.NET/Renci.SshNet/AuthenticationPasswordChangeEventArgs

Answer (score 0):

No. While there's an API in the SSH protocol to change a password on request, the explicitly request is not implemented by the SSH.NET library.

In the SSH.NET library, you can only only change the password, if the server asks for it. Typically a servers asks for a password change, when the previous password has expired. In the SSH.NET library, this server request is implemented as the `PasswordExpired` event.

---

Though if you are willing to modify the SSH.NET library, see the `PasswordAuthenticationMethod.Session_UserAuthenticationPasswordChangeRequiredReceived` method. It sends the password change request like:

```
_session.SendMessage(
    new RequestMessagePassword(
        ServiceName.Connection, Username, _password, eventArgs.NewPassword))
```

If you implement your own `AuthenticationMethod` that sends the `RequestMessagePassword` with the `eventArgs.NewPassword` directly in the implementation of the `Authenticate` method, it should do what you need.